# Save data even if the app re-opens - Swift Xcode 6 iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, save

I'm working on a app that can randomize love couples. Just a fun thing, okey!?!? :D
But the problem, or maybe not a problem but a thing that can be much better if I get this thing to be working. In the beginning you need to write in all the names. And thats takes some time... Should I use Core Date? I don't really knows what core data is so I'm not sure. I would love if a god come to me and wrote the full code that can remember an array even if the app and phone shuts down. I have done this in java, is that simpel that it is in java? That would be great!

//Thank, Anton

Comment: If you are managing large amounts of data, use core data, but if you are only storing some names in an array, just use NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

For Heavy, complex data structures you would want to use core data, 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1

But seeing as you just want to store an array, You should look into `NSUserDefaults`.
`NSUserDefaults` will store given data as long as the app is not deleted. You will most likely want to create some kind of custom DataStorage class for this.

```
@interface DataStorage : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayToStore;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
- (void)save;

@end
```

Above is the .h file. As you can see, it follows `NSCoding` protocols. That provides access to methods which allow you to encode data. You will use the save method to write the data to disk.

```
#import "DataStorage.h"

@implementation DataStorage


@synthesize arrayOfPeople = _arrayToStore;

+ (DataStorage *)sharedInstance
{
    static DataStorage *state = nil;
    if ( !state )
    {
        NSData *data =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DataStorageKey"];

        if (data)
        {
            state = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        }
        else
        {
            state = [[DataStorage alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return state;
}

- (id)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        if (!_arrayToStore) {
            _arrayToStore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {


        if ([decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"DataStorageArrayToStore"]) {
            _arrayToStore = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"DataStorageArrayToStore"] mutableCopy];
        }



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:_arrayToStore forKey:@"DataStorageArrayToStore"];
}

- (void)save
{
    NSData *appStateData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:appStateData forKey:@"DataStorageKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}


@end
```

Here is the .m file, which pretty much evaluates to see if there is a saved instance of the class, and if not it will create one. `[DataStorage sharedInstance]`...

when you want to store some data, you will simply make the class available to said file, `#import "DataStorage.m` and then use

```
NSString *testData = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test Data String"];
[[DataStorage sharedInstance].arrayToStore addObject: testData];
[DataStorage sharedInstance] save];
```